# segmentation fault linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I see some similar topic but they didn't help me. I have make linked list, and a function to insert elements.

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} node;

struct node* head;

void insert(struct node* head,int x);
int main(){
    struct node* head = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    int x;
    while(1){
        printf("Please enter number\n");
        scanf("%i", &x);
        insert(head,x);
        print(head); // function that works
    }
    return 0;
}
void insert(struct node* head,int x){
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(head->next != NULL) temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
    free(temp);
}
```

GDB says that I'm getting segmentation fault on the line with the if construction:

```
if(head->next != NULL) temp->next = head;
```

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Check if head itself is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ofcourse it will give segmentation fault. In `if` condition you are accessing `head->next`. `head` is just pointer of type `struct node`. First allocate the memory space and then access the field. Right now you are accessing `(head->next)` which is some inappropriate address in the memory and kernel gives "segmentation fault" to the process. For e.g do `struct node* head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));` and then one can access `head->next`.

Comment: I'm giving head as argument I don't see how this will help. Anyway I have make a new dynamically allocate var, and set it = head. I'm still getting seg. fault.

Comment: Well in print function you may be accessing freed memory. You can free memory in print function after its access.

Comment: I am voted down :( jus coz one didnot specify his problem precisely.

Comment: user3181029 - Did the program work correctly ? I mean when you type a number it should add it to the beginning of the linked list?

Comment: Yes it did. Nonone knows what you are doing in "print" function. I commented out the "print" function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check `head` before calling `if(head->next != NULL) temp->next = head;`. head may contain NULL. So add `if(head != NULL)` before `if(head->next != NULL) temp->next = head;`

**EDIT:**
If you posted full code while asking question it is easy to help you in proper way. Now people are thinking that we answered wrong and they are down voting. ok anyway here is my answer.
You should not call `free(temp);` in insert function it self. Because you are going to access that memory in `print` function. You are freeing allocated memory in `insert()` it self and trying to access in print function. That is causing the segmentation fault. Remove `free(temp);` from insert function.

Comment: I;m getting seg. fault again this is what I have done :
if(head != NULL){
  if(head->next != NULL) temp->next = head;
}

Comment: @user3181029 did you allocated memory for head before passing it to insert() ?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't post the main function sorry, I have post it now.
This is my main function after adding the head there and removing it from globals

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are declaring two variables with same name (head) but in different scopes:

```
struct node* head;

void insert(struct node* head,int x);
int main()
{
  struct node* head = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

In the insert function you dereference 'head' before checking if 'head' is NULL or not. Always check for null and never assume anything. **At the end of the function you free the newly created node**, that is wrong as well. Finally, the argument to the insert function is not correct, you need to pass the address of the pointer in order to be able to change what head points to.

The function should look something like this instead

```
void insert(struct node** head,int x)
{
  struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  temp->data = x;
  temp->next = NULL;

  assert( head != NULL ); // should always be an address

  if ( *head == NULL ) 
  {
    *head = temp; // done, first in list
  }
  else // insert as first in list
  {
    tmp->next = *head; 
    *head = tmp;       
  }
}
```

you should then call it like:

```
insert(&head,x);
```